# how to get Intersection of set of string in maps in java

Tags: java, collections, set

I have a Map of key pair as (String,Set(Integer)). In which each entry denotes an occurrences of an element. Now what I want to do is to have a set of elements from that keys and find the occurrences where all those have simultaneously happened. The set will be incremented gradually.

I am stuck on how to form a method with Set of String and Map of String,Set-Integer as input which will return an Set of Integer as output which will contain the intersection of all integers in set in map corresponding to keys from a set of strings.

this is my map

```
Map<String,Set<Integer>> transactions = new HashMap<String,Set<Integer>>();
```

This is the Set of string

```
Set<String> check_set
```

Now question is how to make this method

```
Set<Integer> getIntersection(Map<String,Set<Integer>> transactions, Set<String> check_set)
```

Which will return intersection of all the Set of integers corresponding to the keys in set of string.
I know i have to use retainAll function, but what i cant figure out is how to use it.
It is a bit confusing.

Comment: It looks to me as though all you need to do is create a result Set<Integer> containing the elements of any arbitrary value from `transactions`. Iterate over check_set looking up the corresponding value from transactions, and intersect that with your result set.

Answer (score 0):

It's already mentioned here [Set Interface Bulk Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) in *Oracle Java Tutorials* and explained in detail along with examples.

[s1.retainAll(s2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) — transforms s1 into the intersection of s1 and s2. (The intersection of two sets is the set containing only the elements common to both sets.)

---

To calculate the union, intersection, or set difference of two sets nondestructively (without modifying either set), the caller must copy one set before calling the appropriate bulk operation.

```
Set<Type> intersection = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
intersection.retainAll(s2);
```

Comment: I understand that. I know in order to have an intersection of two sets i have to use retainAll() function. What i cant figure out is how to make a method to get an intersection of a SET of set of Strings(get it?) from inside a map.

Comment: Are you talking about intersection between Set<String> and keys of Map that are strings? It will be better if you can explain it using sample code.

Comment: do you want to retrieve unique keys or values from Map? Simply loop over values and call `intersection.retainAll(values)`, check for size after it if `intersection.size()==0` then there is no need to iterate all the values, simply come out of the loop.

Comment: I added some more information in question.

Comment: The set of keys will keep on increasing which is why i cant figure out how to formulate a logic for it.

Comment: why `check_set` is a `Set<String>` instead of `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: because it is a set of keys and not values.

Comment: Coffee=[1, 4], Bread=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Sundae=[3, 4, 5]
... If this is my map then check_set can have {"Bread","Sundae"} and the method should return {3,4,5}

Comment: Now finally I got it what you want? why did you not mentioned it at first time when you posted it here?

Comment: this is my first question here. I guess i didn't know how to ask.

Comment: In this sample why {"Coffee","Bread"} is not an answer where {1,4} is common? your requirement is some what not correct. think about it again.

Comment: yes it could be. that was just an example. There will be a large map with many keys and value. The check_set will be a subset of keys of map and method should return intersections of those keys only.

Comment: now you are making me confused. last comment :`method should return intersections of those keys` previous comment : `method should return {3,4,5}`

Comment: sorry, what i meant was that method should return an intersection of values of keys present in check_set.

Comment: So in this example there will be no match, am I right? if yes then what will be the resultant keys and values?

Comment: in example with check_set having {"Coffee","Bread"} should return {1,4} as both of these integers are present in the sets of Coffee and Bread.

Comment: why `{"Bread","Sundae"}` is not an answer where `{3,4,5}` is common as you already suggested in your example? If we consider both the cases then there is no common between all three values.

Comment: Answer should be a set of integer. If you check the declaration above, check_set is an input parameter. {3,4,5} is the value which should be returned for {"Bread","sundae"}.. I chose a very poor example.. let me come up with some other less confusing one.

Comment: It already got your point, you need method returns values and set the keys in passed argument, that's OK but my concern is that it's a valid example and until and unless you answer this question the requirement is not clear.

Comment: If the MAP is tea=[1,3,5,7,9], milk=[2,3,6,7,9], sugar=[1,4,6,8,9]... then if check_set is {"tea","milk"} then the method should return values which are present in both tea and milk i.e {3,7,9}. Or if it has {"milk","sugar"} then it should return {6,9}. if it has all three {"sugar","milk",tea"} then it should return {3,9}.

Comment: are my requirements clear now?

Comment: if `super = [1,9]` then what will be the output? My concern is that if there are more than one possibilities than what will be output?

Comment: If sugar=[1,9] then the output will be [1,9] as it is the intersection between the sets of tea and sugar .